# javascript: unknown-why undefined variables

Tags: javascript, function, object, appendchild

The  following code is to make a lever move back and forth and change the color of a square.  However, the following is the bare bones of the elements involved where I am stuck.  The error IE gives me is "value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined"  This is located at the XXXXX's in the code.  Also, I was getting confused when to use " " and when to us ' ' when I wrote this code.  It runs fine until the XXXX's where I get an error.

```
  function sliderBox(style){ 
     this.style = style;
     var line = null;
     var bar = null;
     var divElem1 = document.createElement('div');
     this.divElem = divElem1.setAttribute('class', 'sliderBox');

    this.constructDOM = function(){ 
     line = new sliderLine();
     bar = new sliderBar(style);
     var ldE = line.divElem;  
     ldE.appendChild(bar.divElem);  XXXXXX PROBLEM HERE
     var tdE = this.divElem;
     tdE.appendChild(line.divElem);
   }    


 }

  function sliderLine(){
    var divElem1 = document.createElement('div');
    this.divElem = divElem1.setAttribute("class", "sliderLine");
  }

  function sliderBar(style){
    this.style = style;
    var divElem1 = document.createElement('div');
    var sBs = "sliderBar" + style;
    this.divElem = divElem1.setAttribute('class', sBs);
  }
```

Anybody know?

Comment: node.setAttribute() returns undefined, not node

Comment: @user943702 what do you mean?

Comment: that the .setAttribute method does do the job but it the return value is not the object (context) itself but undefined. @user963070 I suggest you move to JavaScript learning first and then solve problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assiging divElem to the return value of setAttribute in the last line of your code. The return value of setAttribute is null or undefined [1]. When you try to appendChild in the line marked with XXXX this gives an error. You should change you sliderBar function to

```
function sliderBar(style){
   this.style = style;
   var divElem1 = document.createElement('div');
   var sBs = "sliderBar" + style;
   divElem1.setAttribute('class', sBs);
   this.divElem = divElem1;
}
```

[1] http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

In short, `element.setAttribute` method returns nothing(see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-setAttribute)). In other words, you assign nothing to `this.divElem` in sliderLine constructor. That's why property `divElem` of `line`(a sliderLine instance) is nothing. "nothing" may be implemented as `undefined` or `null`, which does not obtain any property. So IE gave us "object is null or undefined" when we try to access a property on `null` or `undefined`.